# Set RegistryValueKind from a method param

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to set RegistryValueKind with a parameter from a method but this is not working, it looks like it can't be set from a parameter. Is there a way to get around this?

```
static bool TrySetKey(string Dir, string Value, string Data, string ValueKind)
{
    if (!CanReadKey(Dir))
        return false;
    using (RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Dir, true))
        if (RegKey == null)
            return false;
        RegKey.SetValue(Value, Data, RegistryValueKind.ValueKind);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Solution: I should mention that I changed the string parameter for Data to an Object so I can pass different values.

```
static bool TrySetKey(string Value, Object Data, RegistryValueKind ValueKind)
{
   // code here 
     RegKey.SetValue(Value, Data, ValueKind);
   return true;
}

TrySetKey("Value Name", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RegistryValueKind` is an enum, So you cannot take its value from string, better to Change your method signature like the following:

```
static bool TrySetKey(string Dir, string Value, string Data, RegistryValueKind ValueKind)
{
   // code here 
   // and set value like this
     RegKey.SetValue(Value, Data, ValueKind);
   return true;
}
```

So that you can call this method like this :

```
TrySetKey("Value Name", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works I have edited my first post if other people have the same question.

Comment: @12shadow12 : Glad to hear that it helped. Anyway happy to help you.